# How to split image in rows and columns using OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, detection

How to detect and split the stamps of each image using OpenCV (C++ or python)?

Below are two sample images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What programming language are you using? Could you please add it to your question's tags?

Comment: i'm using opencv in python or c++

Comment: Could you please add the source code of what you have tried so far? Please try [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50850319/edit) instead of posting comments to it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be to use contouring/edge detection to extract the desired shape.
You should try out Canny Edge Detector, it has support on OpenCV.

If you're trying contouring, you will have to try changing the number of iteration of the dilation or `erosion` functions (depending on your code) so that each stamp remains a separate entity.

Following that, you can simply find extract each contour and extract them into separate images. This snippet should help you out with the above mentioned part

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
cv2.rectangle(rgb_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), settings['outline_color'],settings['outline_thickness'])
roi = rgb_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite("/Path/",roi)
#Settings is a dictionary, ignore it.
```